# convert string from url parameter to timestamp using strtotime()

Tags: php, timestamp

I send parameter which contain string date format (Y-m-d H:i:s) to php backend and convert it using strtotime() function

But it seems didn't work

```
$urlParameter = '2022-09-30%2010:36:13';

$timestamp = strtotime($urlParameter);

echo $timestamp
//result null
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: You have `%20` in the string which means that it was encoded, so `urldecode()` the value first.  Also check your variable name spelling as you have different names.

Comment: @NigelRen thank you, didn't realize the % exists, it works